# Alter response to graphQL query

Tags: types, graphql

I'm new to graphQL.  I have a query that returns an object like this:

```
 export interface MyObject {
    id: string;
    fName?: string;
    lName?: string;
    dateOfBirth?: string;
  }
```

Some of these fields will contain non-alphanumeric characters, and I'd like to strip those out of the response (strip out the alphanumeric characters, not the entire field).
I'm trying something like this:

```
  const { loading: isDataLoading, data: myData } = useQuery(getData, {
    variables: { id: id },
    onCompleted: () => {
      myData.data.dateOfBirth = myData.data.dateOfBirth.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
    }
  });
```

But this isn't working.  I get, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'dateOfBirth' of object '#<Object>'`.  How can I fix my data before I work with it?  I don't control the backend nor do I control how data gets into the backend.

Answer (score 0):

`data` (which you've aliased to `myData`) is a variable controlled by the `useQuery` hook - the hook can change it but your code can't.

You can however make a copy.

```
const dateOfBirth = myData.data.dateOfBirth.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')
```

If you want to perform a relatively expensive operation on the data returned by `useQuery` (typically a filter and/or sort on an array) then you can do that in a `useMemo` hook.